# vhdl package export symbols it includes from another package

Tags: vhdl

Let's say I have a package strkern (I do) which exports function: strlen

```
package strkern is
    function strlen(s: string) return natural;
end package strkern;
```

I write a new package stdstring which defines lots of exciting new operators, but also wants to reexport strlen

```
use work.strkern.all;

package stdstring is
    -- rexport strlen
    -- define exciting new operators
end package stdstring
```

So if one codes

```
use work.stdstring.all;
```

You get strlen(), and the exciting new operators.
How does one "re export" a function/type import from a sub package?
Short of having a dummy implementation with a new name that just calls the "to be imported" implementation

```
function strlen(s: string) return natural is
    return strkern.strlen(s);
end function strlen;
```

Comment: Re-export is a misnomer. Declarations from packages are made visible through use clauses. For subprograms those declarations also have a subprogram definition found in the package body that is dynamically elaborated and executed during a procedure call or function call.

Answer (score 3):

By providing a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example:

```vhdl
package strkern is
    function strlen(s: string) return natural;
end package strkern;

package body strkern is
    function strlen(s: string) return natural is
    begin
        return s'length;
    end function;
end package body;

use work.strkern.all;  -- NOT USED in this foreshortened example
package stdstring is
    -- rexport strlen
    -- define exciting new operators
    alias strlen is work.strkern.strlen [string return natural];
end package stdstring;

use work.stdstring.all;
entity foo is
end entity;

architecture fum of foo is
begin
    assert false 
        report "strlen of ""abcde"" is " & integer'image(strlen("abcde"))
        severity NOTE;
end architecture;
```

we can demonstrate the use of an alias in a package to provide visibility of a declaration of a function found in another package.

```
ghdl -r foo
std_flub_up.vhdl:25:5:@0ms:(assertion note): strlen of "abcde" is 5
```

The questions code snippets don't demonstrate any 'exciting new operators' where operator is specific to predefined operators in VHDL. See IEEE Std 1076-2008 9.2 Operators.

The method of using an alias to make name visible is shown in
6.6.3 Nonobject aliases. Note that an alias for a subprogram requires a signature.

Some readers may be curious why the selected name suffix `strlen` is visible in the above MCVe alias. See 12.3 Visibility:

> Visibility is either by selection or direct. A declaration is visible by *selection* at places that are defined as follows:
>
> > a) For a primary unit contained in a library: at the place of the suffix in a selected name whose prefix denotes the library.
> > ...
> > f) For a declaration given in a package declaration, other than in a package declaration that defines an uninstantiated package: at the place of the suffix in a selected name whose prefix denotes the package.
> > ...

Basically a selected name (`work.strkern.strlen`) suffix (`strlen`) declaration occurs in a separate name space defined by the prefix which will designate a primary unit (package `strkern` here in library `work`). The package declaration is made visible by rule a. The suffix is made visible by rule f. The library `work` is made visible by an implicit library declaration (see 13.2 Design libraries).

Comment: Thanks, this worked well for me. I've answered below to show that my strlen() is not quite as trivial as you think

Comment: Some of the exciting new operators are visible below. They're being generated by a python script, so I only setup a few to keep it all readable

Answer (score 1):

You cannot re-export anything from one package in another. The only option is to use both the `strkern` package and the `stdstring` package.

```vhdl
use work.strkern.all;
use work.stdstring.all;
```

I would recommend against creating a dummy implementation, because if a user were to include both packages, the duplicate function signatures will cause both to be invisible as the compiler will not know which one to use. The user will have to be explicit about which function to use:

```vhdl
work.strkern.strlen("Hello world");
work.stdstring.strlen("Hello world");
```

You can create aliases to the functions in the first package, but they cannot have the same name as the original:

```
alias str_len is strlen[string];
```

Maybe you want to investigate context clauses from VHDL2008. These allow you use several libraries and packages in a single context, and can be included elsewhere to include all the clauses in the context. The only issue here is that you are not allowed to use work, because work only means the "current working library". If you were to include a context within a another library, the work reference is now incorrect.

```vhdl
context my_string_packages is
  library my_string_lib;
  use my_string_lib.strkern.all;
  use my_string_lib.stdstring.all;
end context my_string_packages;


library my_string_lib;
context my_string_lib.my_string_packages;
```

Answer (score 0):

Package strdemo is aliasing strlen, strncpy

```
package strdemo is
alias strlen  is work.strkern.strlen[string return natural];
alias strncpy is work.strkern.strncpy [string, string, integer, natural, natural, boolean];

function  "+"(a:string;         b:string)            return string;
function  "-"(a:string;         b:string)            return boolean;
function  "*"(a:integer;        b:character)         return string;
function  "*"(a:boolean;        b:string)            return string;
end package strdemo;
```

Here's the full listing of strkern

```
package strkern is
constant STRING_EOF : character := nul; -- \0 string termination from c

-- We can't assign strings but can easily assign string_segments to variables
-- Making a record instead of array because a record has no operators defined for it.
-- An array already has the & operator.

type string_segment is record
    start, stop: natural;
end record string_segment;    

-- We have 3 kinds of string: string, cstring, vstring. All export functions return vstring
-- There is no functionality difference between the 3, just implementation.

-- All functions accept string and return vstring. They can accept any string type but will
-- always return a vstring. 

subtype cstring is string; -- null terminated c    strlen <= 'length   'left =  1
subtype vstring is string; -- vhdl string          strlen =  'length   'left >= 1

function  strlen(s: string) return natural;
function  safeseg(s: string; ss: string_segment := (0, 0); doreport: boolean := false) return vstring;
procedure strncpy(dest: out cstring; src: string; n: integer := -2; at: natural := 1; from: natural := 1; doreport: boolean := false);
end package strkern;


package body strkern is
-- Error messages
constant safeseg_left:  string := "right operand: ";
constant safeseg_right: string := " overflows strlen: ";

-- Borrow integer whenelse() from stdlib
function whenelse(a: boolean; b, c: integer) return integer is begin
    if a then return b; else return c;
    end if;
end function whenelse;

function ii(i: integer) return vstring is begin 
    return integer'image(i); 
end function ii;

-- These 4 are the only functions/procedures that use & = or segment/index strings

-- strlen is fundamental. It gives the correct answer on any type of string  
function strlen(s: string) return natural is
    variable i: natural := s'left;
begin
    while i < s'right and s(i) /= STRING_EOF loop
        i := i+1;
    end loop;
    
    if s'length = 0 then
        return 0;
    elsif s(i) = STRING_EOF then
        return i-s'left;
    else
        return i+1-s'left;
    end if;
end function strlen;


-- safely segment a string. if a=0 convert a cstring to vhdl string
-- otherwise use strlen and 'left to return correct segment string.

function safeseg(s: string; ss: string_segment := (0, 0); doreport: boolean := false) return vstring is
    constant len: natural := strlen(s); -- strlen is an expensive function with long strings

-- This is the reason for stdstring. Debug reports get very verbose.
    impure function dump return vstring is begin
        return " safeseg(s, (" & ii(ss.start) & ", " & ii(ss.stop) & ")) s'left=" & ii(s'left) & " strlen(s)=" & ii(len);
    end function dump;
begin
    if doreport then -- debug. invokers can switch on doreport
        report dump;
    end if;
    
    if ss.start = 0 then -- if ss.start=0 return the entire string as defined by strlen()
        if len=0 then -- cannot use whenelse here 
            return "";
        else
            return s(s'left to s'left + len-1);
        end if;
    else 
        assert ss.stop <= len report safeseg_left & natural'image(ss.stop) & safeseg_right & dump;
        return s(s'left + ss.start-1 to s'left + whenelse(ss.stop=0, s'length, ss.stop) -1);
    end if;
end function safeseg;


-- The only way to assign strings
-- strncpy(dest, src) is effectively strcpy(dest, src) from C
-- It will non fail assert on overflow followed by an array out of bounds error
procedure strncpy(dest: out cstring; src: string; n: integer := -2; at: natural := 1; from: natural := 1; doreport: boolean := false) is
    constant srclen:    natural := strlen(src);
    constant destspace: integer := dest'length + 1 - at;
    variable copylen:   integer := srclen + 1 - from;

    impure function dump return vstring is begin
        return " strncpy(str(" & ii(dest'length) & "), str(" & ii(srclen) & "), " & ii(n) & ", " & ii(at) & ", " & ii(from) & ")"; 
    end function dump;
begin
    if doreport then
        report dump;
    end if;
    
    if n >= 0 and copylen > n then
        copylen := n;
    end if;
    
    if n = -1 and copylen > destspace then
        copylen := destspace;
    end if;
    
    assert copylen <= destspace report "overrun" & dump;
    
    if copylen > 0 then
        dest(at to at + copylen - 1) := src(from to from + copylen - 1);
    end if;
    if copylen < destspace then
        dest(at + copylen) := STRING_EOF;
    end if;
end procedure strncpy;
end package body strkern;
```